# Remove VPN in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

How do I remove a VPN I no longer need from the list of Network Connections in Windows 7?

Answer (score 7):

Simply click the `Windows Orb`, then start typing `Network Connections` in to search and click on `View Network Connections` when it becomes visible.

Simply delete the VPN connection you do not need.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it did not show. Now, if I type 'Network Connections' it shows 5 out of 17 matches within Control Panel, none of which are the one I want. But if I click on 'Control Panel' to get all search results, or if I type 'View Network Connections', then I can get to it. Thanks!

Comment: i went there today, too. And at first it didn't show anything other than my LAN connection. Pushing `F5` (i.e. refresh) made the VPN connection appear.